# Time values off slightly when adding to database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, pytz

I am attempting to create a add appointment slots to my database programmatically, but I noticed my values for `date_start` and `date_end` are slightly off.

What I've done is store weekday and weekend time slots in arrays of pairs of tuples. The tuples contain an hour and a minute value, which are passed as a parameter to the internal `appointments` function where they're unpacked and passed to the `datetime` constructor.

### managers.py

The function in question is `create_appointments` (specifically `appointments`) which has the time slots hard-coded and calls on `create_appointment` for each pair.

```py
import pytz

from django.db import models
from datetime import date, datetime
from project.settings import TIME_ZONE # 'America/Chicago'


class AppointmentManager(models.Manager):
    def create_appointment(self, date_start, date_end):
        from booking.models import Appointment

        try:
            appt = Appointment.objects.create(
                profile=None,
                date_start=date_start,
                date_end=date_end,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return (False, e)
        return (True, appt)


    def create_appointments(self, date=date.today(), tzinfo=pytz.timezone(TIME_ZONE), verbose=False):
        from booking.models import Appointment

        def appointments(times):
            for pair in times:
                hour_start, minute_start = pair[0]
                hour_end, minute_end = pair[1]

                date_start = datetime(
                    date.year,
                    date.month,
                    date.day,
                    hour_start,
                    minute_start,
                    tzinfo=tzinfo,
                )

                date_end = datetime(
                    date.year,
                    date.month,
                    date.day,
                    hour_end,
                    minute_end,
                    tzinfo=tzinfo,
                )

                valid, response = self.create_appointment(date_start, date_end)

                if not valid:
                    raise response

                if verbose:
                    print('%s %s' % (response.date_start, response.date_end))


        def weekend():
            appointments([
                [ (8, 0),  (8, 50)], #  8am
                [ (9, 0),  (9, 50)], #  9am
                [(10, 0), (10, 50)], # 10am
                [(11, 0), (11, 50)], # 11am

                [(13, 0), (13, 50)], #  1pm
                [(14, 0), (14, 50)], #  2pm
                [(15, 0), (15, 50)], #  3pm

                [(17, 0), (17, 50)], #  5pm
                [(18, 0), (18, 50)], #  6pm
                [(19, 0), (19, 50)], #  7pm
            ])


        def weekday():
            appointments([
                [(17, 0), (17, 50)], # 5pm
                [(18, 0), (18, 50)], # 6pm
                [(19, 0), (19, 50)], # 7pm
            ])


        options = {
            0: weekday,
            1: weekday,
            2: weekday,
            3: weekday,
            4: weekday,
            5: weekend,
            6: weekend,
        }

        try:
            options[date.weekday()]()
        except Exception as e:
            return (False, e)
        return (True, Appointment.objects.filter(
            date_start__year=date.year,
            date_start__month=date.month,
            date_start__day=date.day,
        ))
```

When I run with the verbosity flag enabled, I get the following.

Expected result:

```
2019-06-15 08:00:00-05:00 2019-06-15 08:50:00-05:00
2019-06-15 09:00:00-05:00 2019-06-15 09:50:00-05:00
2019-06-15 10:00:00-05:00 2019-06-15 10:50:00-05:00
…
2019-06-21 17:00:00-05:00 2019-06-21 17:50:00-05:00
2019-06-21 18:00:00-05:00 2019-06-21 18:50:00-05:00
2019-06-21 19:00:00-05:00 2019-06-21 19:50:00-05:00
```

Actual result:

```
2019-06-15 08:00:00-05:51 2019-06-15 08:50:00-05:51
2019-06-15 09:00:00-05:51 2019-06-15 09:50:00-05:51
2019-06-15 10:00:00-05:51 2019-06-15 10:50:00-05:51
…
2019-06-21 17:00:00-05:51 2019-06-21 17:50:00-05:51
2019-06-21 18:00:00-05:51 2019-06-21 18:50:00-05:51
2019-06-21 19:00:00-05:51 2019-06-21 19:50:00-05:51
```

So the base times are correct, but the timezone offsets are not. Why am I repeatedly getting this false value?

I am using SQLite for development and plan on using PostgreSQL for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")
<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' LMT-1 day, 18:09:00 STD>
>>> offset = 24*3600 - 18*3600 - 9*60
>>> (offset//3600, offset//60%60)
(5, 51)
```

using pytz.timezone to set tzinfo will use an older timezone system the we use today, `.localize` seems to solve this issue and should be used instead.

```py
>>> # pytz.timezone(...).localize(datetime(...))
>>> pytz.timezone("America/Chicago").localize(datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15, 17, 00)).isoformat(" ")
'2019-06-15 17:00:00-05:00'
```

instead of

```py
>>> # datetime(..., tzinfo=pytz.timezone(...))
>>> datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15, 17, 00, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")).isoformat(" ")
'2019-06-15 17:00:00-05:51'
```

---

edit: by the way don't use instances of objects as a default argument such as `date=date.today()`

date.today() is called when the function is created, and the resulting object will be reussed.
if the script would run for more then a day, it would still use the date of the previous day. use the following construct instead.

```py
def create_appointments(self, date=None, tzinfo=pytz.timezone(TIME_ZONE), verbose=False):
    if date is None:
        date = date.today()
    ...
```

Comment: Checking several other timezones returns wrong values afaict. To the best of my knowledge London has never been 1 minute behind GMT and Paris is not 9 minutes ahead of it. Ah: it is defaulting to figures based on 19th century tables: http://blog.qax.io/pytz-and-strange-timezones/

Comment: This is very helpful; do you have a link to the `.localize` documentation?

Comment: @MattMcCarthy https://pypi.org/project/pytz/ this is the module documentation. you could call help on a localized function `help(pytz.timezone("America/Chicago").localize)` to get a more detailed documentation on the function.